# Convert characters to dates and display them in correct order in plotly axis

Tags: r, plotly

I create the plotly bar chart below in my `shiny` app. This may seem correct but when I subset based on date the months are displayed in wrong order. How can I make them be in the correct order? Can I convert them to dates when they are in this form?

```
re<-structure(list(month_year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
                                              7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, NA), .Label = c("2020-Mar", 
                                                                                                   "2020-Apr", "2020-May", "2020-Jun", "2020-Jul", "2020-Aug", "2020-Sep", 
                                                                                                   "2020-Oct", "2020-Nov", "2020-Dec", "2021-Jan", "2021-Feb", "2021-Mar", 
                                                                                                   "2021-Apr"), class = "factor"), First = c(862, 19117, 121572, 
                                                                                                                                             588123, 882046, 1401836, 1065476, 813419, 834485, 916300, 1264637, 
                                                                                                                                             1369098, 2025535, 474664, 267236), lab = c("862", "19,117", "121,572", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "588,123", "882,046", "1,401,836", "1,065,476", "813,419", "834,485", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "916,300", "1,264,637", "1,369,098", "2,025,535", "474,664", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "267,236")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "data.frame"))
  library(plotly)
  p <- plot_ly() %>% 
    add_bars(data=re, x = ~month_year, y = ~First, 
             marker = list(color = "#3E5B84"), offsetgroup = 1,
             text = ~paste("<b>Country:</b>","<br><b>Date:</b>",month_year,"<br><b>Cases:</b>",lab),
             hovertemplate = paste('%{text}<extra></extra>')) %>%
    layout(title=list(text="worldwide,by selected territories and period",x = 0,y=1,font=list(size=10)),
           showlegend=T,
           xaxis = list(title = "Date",fixedrange = TRUE),
           yaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE),
           margin = list(b = 100),
           barmode = 'group',
           legend=list(title=list(text='<b> Country </b>'))
    )
  
  
  p%>%
    config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c('toImage',"zoom2d","toggleSpikelines","hoverClosestCartesian","hoverCompareCartesian","drawline","autoScale2d" ,"resetScale2d","zoomIn2d","zoomOut2d","pan2d",'select2d','lasso2d'))%>%
    config(displaylogo = FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you please expand your example code to show the filtering issue? Please also include minimal shiny code to replicate.

Comment: The issue isnt with filtering. Its because you used a factor in the month_year. You either need to set it up as ordered and specify the order or you need to convert the column to dates for plotly to understand the implicit ordering of month-year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I first made a date variable out of your month_year column then edited the plotly. In the shinyapp filter on the date column, you can also specify the format of the date filter using `as.Date(date, format = "%b-%Y")`

```
re <- re %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(paste0(month_year,"-1")))
library(plotly)


p <- plot_ly() %>% 
  add_bars(data=re, x = ~date, y = ~First, 
           marker = list(color = "#3E5B84"), offsetgroup = 1,
           text = ~paste("<b>Country:</b>","<br><b>Date:</b>",month_year,"<br><b>Cases:</b>",lab),
           hovertemplate = paste('%{text}<extra></extra>')) %>%
  layout(title=list(text="worldwide,by selected territories and period",x = 0,y=1,font=list(size=10)),
         showlegend=T,
         xaxis = list(title = "Date",tickformat = "%b \n %Y", dtick = 60*60*24*30*1000, tickmode = "linear", tick0 = -1),
         yaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE),
         margin = list(b = 100, r=-0.5),
         barmode = 'group',
         legend=list(title=list(text='<b> Country </b>'))
  )


p%>%
  config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c('toImage',"zoom2d","toggleSpikelines","hoverClosestCartesian","hoverCompareCartesian","drawline","autoScale2d" ,"resetScale2d","zoomIn2d","zoomOut2d","pan2d",'select2d','lasso2d'))%>%
  config(displaylogo = FALSE)
```

the dtick option defaults to millisecs hence the big dtick option there.

[image]

Comment: this is related to your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840800/increase-the-distance-between-y-axis-labels-in-plotly